# tomcat scalability ejb

Tags: tomcat, ejb, scalability, apache-tomee

I'm interested on Tomcat with OpenEJB horizontal scalability configuration, and how it will perform to manage distributed stateless ejb s: on every invocation if it's possible to allocate an instance from another tomcat server like in application server - or if every http request is served integrally on the same tomcat server with all ejb calls in the same server instance.

I'm considering Tomee (tomcat configured with frameworks for Java EE stack) also instead simple Tomcat for the same question.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are using are stateless EJBs then you are going to get an EJB from the local pool. Tomcat + OpenEJB will work exactly the same way as TomEE.